# ffmpeg What's the difference between -to and -t options?

Tags: ffmpeg

Command

```
ffmpeg -ss 5:09 -i foo.mkv -to 5:10 -c copy bar.mkv
```

works exactly like

```
ffmpeg -ss 5:09 -i foo.mkv -t 5:10 -c copy bar.mkv
```

Is it a bug?

Using Zeranoe git-bd75651 for Windows 64-bit

```
>ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version N-57906-gbd75651
built on Nov  4 2013 18:09:19 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 -
-disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enabl
e-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --ena
ble-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmo
dplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb
--enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger
--enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enab
le-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis -
-enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-li
bxvid --enable-zlib
libavutil      52. 51.100 / 52. 51.100
libavcodec     55. 41.100 / 55. 41.100
libavformat    55. 21.100 / 55. 21.100
libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
libavfilter     3. 90.101 /  3. 90.101
libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
```

Comment: surprisingly, the man page does not list a `-to` option. http://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg

Comment: @FrankThomas Absolutely outdated manpage..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The real answer is that it works as expected. The `-ss` option specified before the input lets ffmpeg seek to that position first and then start encoding at 00:00:00 as a time stamp.

This means that it does not matter if you encode for 5 minutes with `-t` or encode up to 00:05:00 with `-to` – because you started at 00:00:00.

If you want to start at a later timestamp, cut the file by using `-ss` after `-i`. That way, ffmpeg will encode, but start outputting at the specified time stamp, which makes the options work as *you* expect them to.

Comment: wow that's a real gotcha! thank god i found your answer quickly enough, i could have lost days to this

Answer (score 6):

From ffmpeg [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)

> ‘-t duration (output)’ Stop writing the output after its duration
>   reaches duration. duration may be a number in seconds, or in
>   hh:mm:ss[.xxx] form.
>
> -to and -t are mutually exclusive and -t has priority.
>
> ‘-to position (output)’ Stop writing the output at position. position
>   may be a number in seconds, or in hh:mm:ss[.xxx] form.
>
> -to and -t are mutually exclusive and -t has priority.

Comment: I still don't get it as both this options give the same result: 5:12 length video

Comment: @Vantuz No it is not a bug, they work similarly but the difference `-t` stops writing the output after the duration provided, while `-to` will stop at a postion given

Comment: `-to` gets position relatively output file? So, is there a way i can specify as stop point position relatively input file? So as i could get 1 min video specifying 5:00 as start point and 6:00 as end?

Comment: @meda Not sure I understand... if I try something like `-ss 00:33:21 file.mpg -to 00:33:22 -vf fps=15` it starts generating hundreds of frames before I stop it, when I only expected 15!

Comment: I still don't see any difference between `-t` and `-to` in practice. An example proving their difference (if any) would prove handy.

Comment: I found that we need to move `-to` before `-i` option. It will stop as position relatively input file.

Comment: @NinhPham one has to love those super intuitive options.

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert: It's subtle but big difference that will seem more obvious when splicing and joining different files and sequences by seeking through the files. `-t` as I understand it simply means to include the next [time] worth of data. `-to` sets a hard limit on the output to produce no more than [time] worth of data. So if for example you were concatenating multiple files (1min + 5min), using `-t 2:00` on the second file yields a 3min file while `-to 2:00` yields a 2min file.